# cant subscribe events of an element in angular2

Tags: angular

I try to subscribe and event of form element within angular2 ..
As you see below I run the code and check the developer console of chrome, chrome stops at first debug point(breakpoint1) but dont arrive iniside of subcrive method..(breakpoint2) 
I search on net and it looks everything is fine with my app.. why is it not working ?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl,FormGroup,FormBuilder,Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import { Auth } from '../../services/auth.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
@Component({
    moduleId:module.id,
    selector: 'app-settings',
    template: '<form [formGroup]="form" (ngsubmit)="submitFunc()">
                   <input class="from-control" fromControlName="search">
               </form>'
})
export class SettingsComponent {
    form:FormGroup;
    constructor(private auth: Auth, private fb:FormBuilder){
        debugger//breakpoint1. it comes here..
        this.form=fb.group({
            search:[]
        });
        var searchRef = this.form.get('search');
        searchRef.valueChanges.subscribe(x=> {
            debugger//breakpoint2. but not here..
            console.log(x); 
            });
    }
    submitFunc(){
        console.log("form submitted");
    }
 }
```

Comment: How is `reactivx` related to this question?

Comment: I have imported RxJs next of it there is observable objects I use but its not point yet.. but i think I got your tell, there is not related with rxjs/Rx library so far..

Comment: I think if you still have a problem it would be helpful to provide a Plunker that allows to reproduce. I don't see a problem in your code.

Comment: can you check this: https://plnkr.co/edit/rUbF4aNpp2gscdhNm8V4?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fromControlName="search"
```

should be

```
formControlName="search"
```

if you change it to (including the typo)

```
[fromControlName]="'search'"
```

you'll see an error message.